# How can I calculate the amplitudes of this signal's harmonics?

Tags: voltage, filter, signal, signal-processing, fourier

How can I calculate the amplitude's of the harmonics? This signal is the voltage of a capacitor bank. There is a few amperes of current on the capacitors in form of PWM. On the signal the 200mV Jumps are the voltage drops on the ESR. The jump occurs when the PWM changes from Ton to Toff or vica versa.[image]
[image]

On the second picture I approximated the 200mV jumps with an instantaneous jump.
How should I derive the Fourier transformation on this signal?

Comment: "Harmonics" is something that a periodic signal has. Your signal isn't periodic.

Comment: Your second drawing has high frequency harmonics. Assuming this repeats, otherwise harmonics do not apply.

Comment: ... and since the position of the harmonics depends on the periodicity, this question can't be answered without you specifying either the periodicity of the signal, or what you really meant with "harmonics".

Comment: This is a whole period. This wave occurs in every PWM cycle. The frequency of the PWM is 20kHz.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the harmonics of a signal by computing the Fourier series of the signal, **given that the signal is periodic**.

You have a non-periodic signal here . However, you can still calculate Fourier series between the full finite interval \$T\$ of the signal, assuming that the signal is 'periodic' with \$T\$, ie., assuming that the signal repeats over and over like that afterwards.

> How should I derive the Fourier transform on this signal?

You can calculate the Fourier transform of the signal using integration by parts. For eg:
[image]

$$F{\{v(t)\}} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty v(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^T v(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$
$$=\int_{0}^{t_0} v(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt+\int_{t_0}^{t_1} v(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt+\int_{t_1}^{t_2} v(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt+\int_{t_2}^{T} v(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt$$

Each of the four terms are simple linear equations for line on the respective intervals, which you can derive if you know the values of \$a, b, c, t0, t1, t2, T \$